# How to load an image directly from url into buffer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, stream

I would like to load an image from Internet directly to stream without saving it to disk an load it again.

Something like
`fs.createReadStream(imageDirectory)`
but just for URLs.

I want to give this image direct to an AI API and don't want to save the image all 300ms to the harddisk.

I read many articles, but never worked

Comment: When requesting an image from the server using `get` from `node:http` you can subscribe to the 'data' event and write the data to the buffer. [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgeturl-options-callback)

Comment: `http.get()` will just give you a readstream directly for the image just like `fs.createReadStream()` gives you.  You don't need to read it all into a buffer to get a readstream for it without ever writing anything to disk.

Comment: I needed this functionality in order the get an image all 300ms from a ip-kamera. In this case i didn't want to harddisk. When there is a detection i want to store the image to the harddisk. Is there a way to store this image (stream) to the harddisk?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

This works now for me:

```
const http = require('http');

function readImage(imageURL, callback) {
    http.get(imageURL, response => {
        callback(response);
    });
}
```